# PHPUnit disable info when doing test

Tags: yii, phpunit, pear

recently i started using phpunit. I like it very much and so on... but some-times unnecessary info annoying me

[image: screenshot]

So, my question is how to disable it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phpunit` is stopping support via PEAR channels after december meaning you won't get updates etc to your current installation, you can use a PHAR package or you can use composer to install phpunit
see

- http://pear.phpunit.de/
- [phpunit pear end-of-life announcement](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method)

to remove the error reinstall using alternative install methods see for more details

- [phpunit installation documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)

you can remove pear installation with this command

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

and you can install using phar with these commands

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Edit: Note you need additional optional dependencies for yii( which PEAR may have handled) to be able to run test cases and so if you are using composer use

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit>=3.7.*" 
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit-selenium=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit-story=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/dbunit=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/php-invoker=*'
```

Comment: Maybe my quesetion is dumpy)) but how to "chmod +x" in windows8?

Comment: you don't need to :) , but i would recommend you to check composer/phpunit documentation on how to get your PATH configured etc for windows if you want to install globally.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the PEAR version of PHPUnit:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

The instructions for installing the new version of PHPUnit are here:

http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/installation.html